# How to group embedded objects within an array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents structured in this form:

```
Item:[{
  product:"shovel"
  price: 100
  dateAdded: 2018-11-28 18:28:12.356
 }
 {
  product:"wheel barrow"
  price: 500
  dateAdded: 2018-11-28 18:28:12.357
 }
 {
  product:"Boot"
  price: 500
  dateAdded: 2018-11-29 18:29:12.357
 }
]
```

and i want to  group the objects within the array based on the day they were added i.e producing the form:

```
Item:[
 [
  {

  product:"Shovel"
  price: 100
  dateAdded: 2018-11-28 18:28:12.356
 }
 {
  product:"Wheel barrow"
  price: 500
  dateAdded: 2018-11-28 18:28:12.357
 }
 ]
 [
  {
   product:"Boot"
   price: 500
   dateAdded: 2018-11-29 18:29:12.357
 }
 ]
]
```

any idea on the aggregation query using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can group on `$dayOfYear` and use `$dateFromString` to get a date from your `string` like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        $dayOfYear: {
          $dateFromString: {
            dateString: "$dateAdded"
          }
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$CURRENT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

The result would be like:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
        "dateAdded": "2018-11-29 18:29:12.357",
        "price": 500,
        "product": "Boot"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
        "dateAdded": "2018-11-28 18:28:12.356",
        "price": 100,
        "product": "shovel"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
        "dateAdded": "2018-11-28 18:28:12.357",
        "price": 500,
        "product": "wheel barrow"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which you can then flatten trivially with JS and `Array.reduce` etc.